# Release mode giving error in .NET Console Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, dll, console-application

I have one ASP.NET application. When I build it in debug mode, build getting succeed. But when I use release mode to build, It is giving me error as below,

[image: Error Image]

In my system I have only "C" drive, still it is saying, "Failed to copy on "L" location.

**Note: I took this application from VSO. So someone else have already worked on it.**

What configuration I need to change to make it work?

Comment: Check your projects output path.Project properties -> Build

Comment: Have you tried clean + rebuild, and restarting visual studio? Sometimes that fixes issues like this.

Comment: Output path: "bin\Release\"

Comment: I added all debug/bin dlls into release/bin folder as well.

Comment: Can you please check you pre-build or post-build scripts? There should be some reference there for copying files to L drive which you don't have.

Answer (score 0):

In your Reference folder for each of the dll that you have added click on each of them and in property window set Copy Local= true that will copy all files that required in deployment to bin and then try to deploy.